# Filter an Array of Object in DataWeave use for Mulesoft

Tags: transform, dataweave, mulesoft

**Can anyone let me know how can I transform this input json I have tried with below transformation but didn't worked.**

I have tried to used filter function and groupBy function, but for Multiple output it is failing the testCase.

tried with this method
`

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.Bd map (val,index) ->{
    "d23": val,
    "lt":(payload.output2 filter(payload.Bd contains val) map(Value) -> 
    {
        Val34: Value.PId
        }
    )
         
}
```

`input -`

```
[
  {
    "Val34": "968",
    "d23": "Y1"
  },
  {
    
    "Val34": "958",
    "d23": "Y2"
  },
  {
    
    "Val34": "951",
    "d23": "Y2"
  }
]
```

`expected output -`

```
[
  {
    "d23": "Y1",
    "lt": [
      {
        "Val34": "968"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "d23": "Y2",
    "lt": [
      {
        "Val34": "958"
      },
      {
        "Val34": "951"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

`

Comment: The question should have more information on the expected output. From what I could infer you want to get Val34 values based on d23 value grouping.

Comment: Is it always going to be `Val34` or can it be `Van<other digits>` too?

Comment: there will be other variables also,for multiple inputs like "d24": "value" also, but we have to add logic to transform with two  values "Val34": "",  "d23": "".

Answer (score 2):

Group by d23 values and map all the rest:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload groupBy ((item, index) -> item.d23) pluck {
    d23: $[0].d23,
    lt: ($.Val34 map (l,indOfl) -> {Val34: l})
}
```

Comment: for multiple input we need to get in automated form, there will be more than 10 input object.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple inputs? You mean there are more arrays? The answer fits the question correctly, if there is something more you want to handle then question lacks the details required to answer it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try first groupingBy 2nd key value pair.. I assumed "d23": "Y1", "d23": "Y3" will be in position `index[1]` .

Further you can map on grouped elements and access index[0]

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload groupBy ((item, index) -> item[1])) pluck $ map{
    ($[0][&1]),
    "lt": ($ map(it,in)->(it[&0]))
}
```

Sample Input

```
[
  {
    "Val34": "968",
    "d23": "Y1"
  },
   {
    "Val34": "998",
    "d23": "Y3"
  },

       {
    "Val34": "988",
    "d23": "Y1"
  },
  {
    
    "Val34": "958",
    "d23": "Y2"
  },
  {
    
    "Val34": "951",
    "d23": "Y2"
  }
]
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "d23": "Y1",
    "lt": [
      {
        "Val34": "968"
      },
      {
        "Val34": "988"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "d23": "Y3",
    "lt": [
      {
        "Val34": "998"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "d23": "Y2",
    "lt": [
      {
        "Val34": "958"
      },
      {
        "Val34": "951"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```